# How to properly store and read struct fields separated by '|' in a text file with a byte indicator in C?

Tags: c

Here is my problem:

I want to save three struct fields separated by `|` in a text file. Before these fields I wrote a byte containing the number of bytes necessary to read the three fields. I created a small program in C to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct compras {
    char nome[50];
    int qtd;
    float valor;
};

int main() {
    struct compras dados[7] = {{ "manteiga", 1, 4.5 },
                               { "pao", 1, 7.99 },
                               { "arroz", 2, 10.95 },
                               { "feijao", 3, 9.4 },
                               { "carne", 2, 21.90 },
                               { "detergente", 3, 1.65 },
                               { "sabao", 2, 3.45 }};
    int k;
    char str[100], str1[100];
    FILE *f = fopen("compras.txt", "w");
    int tam;

    for (k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
        sprintf(str, "%s|%d|%.2f", dados[k].nome, dados[k].qtd, dados[k].valor);
        tam = strlen(str);
        printf("%c%s", tam, str);
        sprintf(str1, "%c%s", tam, str);

        fputs(str1, f);
    }

    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

I created a program to read back this data. It works fine on windows, but it doesn't read correctly the byte representing the size on Linux and in some online IDEs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("compras.txt", "r");
    int ch;
    char str[100];

    while (1) {
        ch = fgetc(f);
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
        fgets(str, ch + 1, f);
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Can someone help?

Comment: `fgets()` reads until a newline. You're not writing newlines to the file.

Comment: You're writing the size as a 1-byte "binary" integer, and the rest of the line as human-readable text.  That can be made to work, but it's at least mildly unconventional, and can be very annoying.

Comment: In your question, you state that reading back the file does not work on Linux. On which platform did you create the file that you are attempting to read back on Linux? Did you create that file also on Linux? Or on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your code and more generally with this approach:

- `sprintf` is risky: there is no protection agains buffer overflow in case the output does not fit in the destination array. Use `snprintf` instead.
- also note that `snprintf` return the number of bytes output, hence you can store the return value to `tam` directly. No need for `strlen()`.
- you output each record twice: once with `printf("%c%s", tam, str);` and another one with `sprintf(str1, "%c%s", tam, str); fputs(str1, f);`
  `
- `printf("%c%s", tam, str);` will store `tam` as a byte value, not a number in textual form. The output is not a text file anymore, which makes it more difficult to debug, and if `tam` happens to be `10`, the output will contain 2 bytes `0x0D 0x0A` on legacy systems. This will definitely cause a problem if you read the file on a different system that does not perform end of line translation, and indeed the second line of output has a length of exactly 10 bytes.
- you do not output a newline at the end of each record, which you probably mean albeit it makes the output file even less readable... Using `fgets(str, ch + 1, f);` and relying on truncation is inelegant.  Instead you should write:

  ```
    fread(str, 1, ch, f);
    str[ch] = '\0';
  ```

Mixing binary contents and text is not a good idea.  Your output format is textual, keep it plain and simple:

- one line per record
- use a standard separator: `,` or `;` would be better than `|` to use the file with other tools that can read or produce CSV files.

If you insist on writing binary data, use binary more for both writing and reading, with `fopen("compras.txt", "wb");` in the writer and `fopen("compras.txt", "rb");` in the reader.

Comment: Also, if they do want a binary format, a single byte for length is rarely sufficient. Four bytes is a more typical choice.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets()` is for reading lines terminated with a newline. On Linux, the newline character is the ASCII code 10, which happens to be the same as the length of your second string. So the length byte of the seconds string is being read by the first `fgets()`, then everything gets out of sync.

And since you're opening the file in text mode, when you write the file on Windows, it will convert `\n` to `\r\n` in the file.

You should open the file in binary mode, then use `fwrite()` and `fread()`.

Writing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct compras {
    char nome[50];
    int qtd;
    float valor;
};

int main() {
    struct compras dados[7] = {{ "manteiga", 1, 4.5 },
                               { "pao", 1, 7.99 },
                               { "arroz", 2, 10.95 },
                               { "feijao", 3, 9.4 },
                               { "carne", 2, 21.90 },
                               { "detergente", 3, 1.65 },
                               { "sabao", 2, 3.45 }};
    int k;
    char str[100], str1[100];
    FILE *f = fopen("compras.txt", "wb");
    int tam;

    for (k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
        sprintf(str, "%s|%d|%.2f", dados[k].nome, dados[k].qtd, dados[k].valor);
        tam = strlen(str);
        printf("%c%s", tam, str);
        sprintf(str1, "%c%s", tam, str);

        fwrite(str1, strlen(str1), 1, f);
    }

    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Reading:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("compras.txt", "rb");
    int ch;
    char str[100];

    while (1) {
        ch = fgetc(f);
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
        int n = fread(str, ch, 1, f);
        str[ch] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is not strictly correct: the length byte of the second string is not being read by the first `fgets()`, because `fgets` reads at most `ch` bytes. Yet the translation is indeed the issue: the second `fgetc()` reads 13 as the length byte of the second record, which is incorrect as only 11 bytes were output, and the `fgets()` actually reads a single byte, the LF that follows the CR. and everything is out of sync. If the file is written (and read) on binary more, using `fread` is not strictly necessary, but certainly more explicit.

Comment: Where does 13 come from on Linux? Linux doesn't translate `\n` to `\r\n`.

Comment: 13 was produced on the legacy system, not linux. There is no pb if the file is read back on the system on which it was written.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "legacy system". Windows converts newline to CRLF, Unix leaves it as LF. The OP says the script fails on Linux.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're talking about. They're not reading the file on the same OS they wrote it on. Opening in binary mode solves that.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code to work only as binary file. Still de same issue on Linux.

```
struct compras{
    char nome[50];
    int qtd;
    float valor;
};

int main(){
    struct compras dados[7] = {{"manteiga",1,4.5},
                                {"pao",1,7.99},
                                {"arroz",2,10.95},
                                {"feijao",3,9.4},
                                {"carne",2,21.90},
                                {"detergente",3,1.65},
                                {"sabao",2,3.45}};
    int k;
    char str[100], str1[100];
    FILE *f = fopen("compras.txt","wb");
    int tam;

    for(k = 0; k < 7; k++){
        tam = sprintf(str,"%s|%d|%.2f",dados[k].nome,dados[k].qtd,dados[k].valor);
        sprintf(str1,"%c%s",tam,str);
        fwrite(str1, sizeof(char),strlen(str1), f);
    }

    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}

int main(){
    FILE *f = fopen("compras.txt","rb");
    int ch;
    char str[100];

    while(1){
        ch = fgetc(f);
        if(ch == EOF)
            break;

        fread(str, sizeof(char),ch, f);
        str[ch] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n",str);
    }
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the hexadecimal code of the files.
The value 13 is saved as 10 on Linux.

[image]

Comment: Although there is nothing wrong with answering your own question, this "answer" does not answer the question in any way. If you want to provide additional information to the question, then please edit the question instead.

Comment: Please also specify whether you get these values when opening the file in `"w"` mode or in `"wb"` mode.

Comment: I believe the statement `"The value 13 is saved as 10 on Linux."` must be incorrect. When I run your posted code on [this online IDE](https://godbolt.org/z/4qEPsqGrd) (which I believe uses Linux), then it produces `0x0D` (13) instead of `0x0A` (10). Please verify whether this statement is correct or whether you made a mistake. If you made a mistake, please specify exactly how and where the second file (the one with `0x0A`) was generated.

Comment: Are you transferring the files between several computers? If so, how are you transferring them? Are you maybe transferring them in text mode instead of binary mode? In that case, the `0x0D` may get translated to `0x0A`. Since the files have a `.txt` extension, your data transfer program may be assuming that they are text files, although they are actually binary files. If that is the case, you may want to rename your files to `.bin`, to prevent this from happening.